# no funciona la validacion con recaptchat v2

Tags: php, html

verán no logro hacer funcionar la validación con recaptcha nose por que se da el error, he intentado cambiar el código sin obtener el resultado

```
$secretkey = 'Lfi9WAAjjjAFjfgddTmñlokjLU0WT9R';
        $response = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secretkey.'&response='.$recaptcha);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response);
        if($responseKeys->success)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Edit -->
agrego el formulario

```
<?php 
    //require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/conexion.php');

    if(isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login'] == "LogIn"){

        $login = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];
        $recaptcha = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];

        if(recaptcha($recaptcha)==true){
            $result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM account WHERE login ='".$login."'");
            if($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
                if(password_verify($password, $row->password)){
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $row->login;

                    mysqli_free_result($result);
                    mysqli_close($link);
                }
            }
            else{
                echo 'usuario no encontrado';
                header('Location: ?p=home');

                mysqli_free_result($result);
                mysqli_close($link);
            }
        }
        else{echo 'error! '.$recaptcha;}
    }

    if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])){
        echo '<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">'.$_SESSION['username'].'</a>';

        echo '
            <div class="dropdown-menu log-in">
                <a href="?p=logout"> cerrar sesion</a>
            </div>';
    }
    else{
?>
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Log In</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu log-in">
    <form class="" action="?p=login" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class"form-group">
            <div class="g-recaptcha captchat" data-theme="dark" data-sitekey="6Lfi9WMUAAAAAFBZ9wyErUktMPOdyruVzwz7z4np"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            <label class="form-check-label">Recordarme</label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="LogIn" class="btn btn-signup col-sm-12">
        <a href="#">olvido la contraseña</a>
    </form>
</div>

<?php   
    }
?>
```

Comment: veo que estas concatenando con una variable llamada `$secret` pero mas arriba tienes la variable llamada `$secretkey` que no usas en el código que muestras

Comment: ¿Ese `$secretkey` es una cadena aleatoria o de verdad es tu clave para reCaptcha?

Comment: he cambiado la variable y no sigue sin funcionar

Comment: ¿Tienes autorizado el dominio que hace la petición? No muestras como está escrito el formulario. Tampoco si recibes algún mensaje de error en la consola del navegador o en la aplicación. En casi todos los tutoriales se añade a la petición la variable `&remoteip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: @OscarR hola gracias por su ayuda; vera ya he agregado el formulario y si verifique que el dominio esta autorizado

Comment: ¿Y has añadido el script? `script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer`. He simplificado el script que tienes con mis claves y funciona correctamente.

Comment: @OscarR si he agregado el script que mencionas, que raro podrias dejarme ver como lo haz modificado?

Comment: En la respuesta te lo añado. Lo básico para probar que funciona. Si lo comparas con lo que tenías aislando las partes podrás detectar que error tenías.

Answer (score 0):

Como comentaba en los comentarios, lo he simplificado hasta dejar una especie de demo bastante simplona para probar lo básico.

Solo tienes que cambiar las claves por las que tienes en la api de Google.

1. La primera carga al no recibir el post retorna un mensaje de que no hay captcha.
2. Si envías sin el captcha activado retorna un mensaje de error de captcha.
3. Si envías con el captcha activado retorna un mensaje de ok.

**Archivo recatcha-test.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('html_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');

function recaptcha($recaptcha)
{
    $secretkey   ='1234567890abcdefghyjklmnop';
    $response    =file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . $secretkey . '&response=' . $recaptcha);
    $responseKeys=json_decode($response);
    if($responseKeys->success) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

$result='Sin valor de captcha';
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    $recaptcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

    if(recaptcha($recaptcha)) {
        $result='Captcha ok!';
    }
    else {
        $result='Captcha error';
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <title>Recaptcha</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1><?php echo $result; ?></h1>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="g-recaptcha captchat" data-sitekey="abcdefghijk987654321"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Enviar">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```